# DOMException : CSSStyleSheet.cssRules :Cannot access rules

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom

I have this error

> "Uncaught DOMException: Failed to read the 'cssRules' property from
> 'CSSStyleSheet': Cannot access rules at HTMLLabelElement."

I tried to read docs etc but it not resolved my issue.
The error happens only when i open locally "page.html" without a server. When i open with for example "live server " or " wamp " the errors doesn't not appear.

**lang-js**

```
let test = [".un", ".deux", ".trois", ".quatre", ".cinq", ".six", ".sept", ".huit"]
console.log(`${test}`)
let test2 = ["allezun", "allezdeux", "alleztrois", "allezquatre", "allezcinq", "allezsix", "allezsept", "allezhuit"]
// let test3 = "opun"
// , "opdeux","optrois","opquatre","opcinq","opsix","opsept","ophuit"
// FOLD UNFOLD CLASS, verifie quand t'appuie sur un bouton. Créer les class fold et unfold suivant si t'a appuyer pour "ouvrir" le bouton ou si t'appuie pour le "fermer"
let stylesheet = document.styleSheets[1]
console.log(document.styleSheets[1])
let animation = document.getElementById("share")
console.log(animation)

animation.addEventListener("click", function () {
    if (animation.classList.contains("unfold")) {
        for (i = 0; i < 8; i++) {

            let un = [...stylesheet.cssRules].find((r) => r.selectorText == `.share.fold ~ ${test[i]}`)
            // console.log(stylesheet.cssRules[un])
            un.style.removeProperty("animation")
            setTimeout(() => {
                un.style.setProperty("opacity", "1")
            }, 650);
        }

        animation.classList.remove("unfold")
        setTimeout(() => {
            animation.classList.add("fold")
        }, 1);

        // console.log(animation.child[0])
        for (i = 0; i < 8; i++) {

            let un = [...stylesheet.cssRules].find((r) => r.selectorText == `.share.fold ~ ${test[i]}`)
            // console.log(stylesheet.cssRules[un])
            un.style.setProperty("animation", `${test2[i]} 0.65s reverse`)
            // setTimeout(() => {
            //     un.style.setProperty("opacity", "0")
            // }, 650);

            // un.style.setProperty("animation", `${test3} 3s`)
        }
        // console.log(animation)
        // console.log(animation.classList.contains)
    }
    else if (animation.classList.contains("fold")) {
        animation.classList.remove("fold")
        setTimeout(() => {
            animation.classList.add("unfold")
        }, 20);

        for (i = 0; i < 8; i++) {

            let un = [...stylesheet.cssRules].find((r) => r.selectorText == `.share.unfold ~ ${test[i]}`)
            // console.log(stylesheet.cssRules[un])
            un.style.setProperty("animation", `${test2[i]} 1.5s`)
        }
    }
    else {
        animation.classList.add("unfold")
        for (i = 0; i < 8; i++) {

            let un = [...stylesheet.cssRules].find((r) => r.selectorText == `.share.fold ~ ${test[i]}`)
            // console.log(stylesheet.cssRules[un])
            un.style.setProperty("animation", `${test2[i]} 1s`)
            setTimeout(() => {
                un.style.setProperty("opacity", "1")
            }, 650);
        }
    }
})
```

**lang-html**

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/bootstrap.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/style2.css">
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Libre+Baskerville&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/all.min.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.1.js" defer></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.9.2/dist/umd/popper.min.js" defer></script>
<script src="./js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="./js/main2.js" defer></script>
<script src="./js/all.min.js"></script>
<title>Accueil</title>
```

If any further information or screen is needed. Tell me

Comment: You are using relative links for the local js and css files. When running within the webserver environment they will be served correctly but not necessarily when using a local, filesystem path ( ie: no webserver )